# Tensorflow what is the tf.contrib.nccl.allsum in new version?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

It seems that from tensorflow 1.13, there is no api such as tf.contrib.nccl.allsum. However, in the Nvidia official GitHub https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans, which uses this old API to reduce sum from different gpu devices as the following.

```
# Sum gradients across devices.
            if len(devices) > 1:
                with tf.name_scope('SumAcrossGPUs'), tf.device(None):
                    for var_idx, grad_shape in enumerate(self._grad_shapes):
                        g = [dev_grads[dev][var_idx][0] for dev in devices]
                        if np.prod(grad_shape): # nccl does not support zero-sized tensors
                            g = tf.contrib.nccl.all_sum(g)
                        for dev, gg in zip(devices, g):
                            dev_grads[dev][var_idx] = (gg, dev_grads[dev][var_idx][1])
```

I am not sure if there is similar api which can achieve the same collective operation cross different devices. I have checked the Tensorflow official website and it seems that programmers prefer to use `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` which hides the raw operation of `NCCL`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In principle you can use [`tf.distribute.NcclAllReduce`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/NcclAllReduce) directly, although I'm not sure how the API works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the same API is `nccl_ops.all_sum`. I have demoed this API by the following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.python.ops import nccl_ops

a = []

with tf.device("/GPU:0"):
    g = tf.constant([1,1])
    print(g)
    a.append(g)
with tf.device("/GPU:1"):
    g = tf.constant([2,2])
    a.append(g)

b = nccl_ops.all_sum(a)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(b))
```

I am not sure what tensorflow team will do in the future. But now we can use it to do the collective operations.

Comment: I think if you do `reducer = tf.distribute.NcclAllReduce(); b = reducer.reduce(tf.distribute.SUM, a, "/GPU:0")` it should do the same as `b = nccl_ops.all_sum(a)`? I do not have a multi-GPU system and I am on Windows so I cannot test but it seems to be how it's used...

Comment: hello dears: so if I am at windows I cannot use nccl.. how can I replace the code above with one that could let use multiple gpus I am kind at the same trouble here please help if it possible ..thanks in advance